# MySQL: Find Duplicated/Conflicted rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Well, I know there are already alot of questions regarding this query, but non of them address my issue.

I've the following table

```
id      name        link        year
1        t1           x1        2013
2        t5           x2        1990
3        t3           x1        2013
4        t2           x9        2011
```

Now I want to get the duplicate records combined with two columns
and the result should be

```
id      name        link        year
1        t1           x1        2013
3        t3           x1        2013
```

here is what I tried so far

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY `link`, `year` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and it returns only one(second) row, so, your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find link and year combination using aggregation for which there are multiple rows. You'll have to join it with your original table to get all the rows for those link and years.

```
select *
from table t
join (
    select link, year
    from table
    group by link, year
    having count(*) > 1
    ) t2 using (link, year);
```